# Where can I find a comprehensive list of gate decompositions used by transpilers?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, resource-request, pyquil

Does anyone know of a web site, paper *etc.* that has a list of "gate decompositions" *e.g.* the kind of decompositions that occur when the transpiler decomposes non-native gates to native gates.

This [document](https://threeplusone.com/pubs/on_gates.pdf) is really nice and has some decompositions, but I'm looking for a kind of summary.

Comment: Generally, a transpiler has a list of target gates that it is compiling to.  Do you have a specific set of target gates in mind?

Comment: @FrankYellin No, I am not targetting a specific architecture (yet) - at present I'm just looking for general gate decomps/identities for long term reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Qiskit's `StandardEquivalenceLibrary` to get a list of gate decompositions.

`StandardEquivalenceLibrary` is an instance of [`EquivalenceLibrary`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.EquivalenceLibrary.html) class. It is used by Qiskit's during transpilation to translate the circuit gates to the target basis. Currently, it contains 80+ equivalences.

You can easily generate a nice image for these equivalences as follows:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library.standard_gates.equivalence_library import StandardEquivalenceLibrary
   
StandardEquivalenceLibrary.draw('equivalence_library.png')
```

If, however, you need a simple list, you can generate it using this code snippet:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library.standard_gates.equivalence_library import StandardEquivalenceLibrary
from IPython.display import display

keys = StandardEquivalenceLibrary._get_all_keys()
# Sort by number of qubits:
keys = sorted(keys, key = lambda x: x.num_qubits)

for key in keys:
    print("{} ({} qubits)".format(key.name, key.num_qubits))
    equivalences = StandardEquivalenceLibrary._get_equivalences(key)
    for equivalence in equivalences:
        display(equivalence.circuit.draw('mpl'))
```

Here is a part of the result:

[image]